# OpenCV2.4.2 converting vector<Point2f> to Mat, and releasing the mat causes error

Tags: opencv, mat

I am changing vector to Mat because for some reason findHomography() produces only zero matrix if vector is taken.

So Following is brief code.

```
{
std::vector<Point2f> img1;
std::vector<Point2f> img2;
Mat mat_from_img1 = Mat(img1,true); 
Mat mat_from_img2 = Mat(img2,true); 
Mat H = cv::findHomography(mat_from_img1,mat_from_img2, CV_RANSAC);

//Do THINGS

}//as soons as getting out of this scope, 
//it calls ~MAT() then Mat::release and causes memory reading violation error.
```

How can I properly convert vector to mat in order to avoid the error?
I tried

Mat mat_from_img1 = Mat(img1,true); either

Comment: Since `Mat mat_from_img1 = Mat(img1,true)` copies the data it has to allocate space for it. You would have a memory leak if the data wasn't released. What is the code where you get the "memory reading violation error"?

Comment: Passing a vector of `Point2f` is the correct way to do it - if you are getting a bad result, you probably don't have enough good points. Try using `CV_LMEDS` instead of `CV_RANSAC` and see if that makes any difference. In your code snippet, you don't actually push any points into the vectors anyway, which I'm assuming is not what you *actually* do?

Comment: passing vector to findHomography is correct way but I don't know why it returns zero matrix if I pass vector. I have to use matrix to get correct H matrix. I realized that when destroying mat H, causes memory violation reading error.

Comment: Oh I found it, it's just my linker problem. In release mode, I used a debug mode lib.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to convert those vectors to Mats. You can pass them directly to [cv::findHomography()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography#findhomography) - it takes an `InputArray`, and an [InputArray can be a std::vector](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#inputarray-and-outputarray).

See the example at 
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

Check what is in img1 and img2 -- according to your code they are empty!